# Secure Laravel API with keycloak using socialite provider

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, keycloak, laravel-socialite

im using Keycloak for an SSO to authenticate user that already exist in server (keycloak). I used Socialite provider and i can now authenticate user and access their token on Keycloak. But i want now to store this token during the session and verifie in each call for api from vue js that the user is already authenticated.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Socialite::driver('keycloak')->redirect();
});

Route::get('/callback/keycloak', function (){
    $user = Socialite::driver('keycloak')->user();
    dd($user);
});
```

[User Info from Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEVaa.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing server-side processing.
Normally with an implementation like this, you would have to create your own session-token and store it in a place that will be reserved for the client (cookie, session, etc.). or you can send to client for storage by javascript.
In this case you can also store `$user->token`.

Another way is to implement keycloak login in vuejs. This is the way I like to use it because it separates the login and authentication process. And the server side doesn't care how the user logs in, as long as there is a valid session-token.

https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-js